# Concerns with modifying properties of a model before processing them with post

Tags: spring-mvc

In my application I have more than one Spring controllers, which process post requests with the same domain object ComplexObject:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processComplexForm (
        @NotNull @Valid @ModelAttribute("complexObject") ComplexObject compexObject,
        BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        //implementation
    }

}

public class ComplexObject {
          private String myProperty;
}
```

Now I want to give users the freedom to write spaces in one of the properties in the form. So I need to remove all spaces from the property, in order to unify the input. And I want to make this only on one place, and not in all controllers, which use the ComplexObject.

My solution is to remove all empty spaces in the setter method of the property, like this:

```java
public setMyProperty (String myProperty) {
    this.myProperty = myProperty.replace(" ", "");
}
```

Do you see any concerns with this solution, and do you have a more elegant and safe solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds reasonable enough to me, although you might want to use `StringUtils.replaceChars()` which is null-safe - just in case `myProperty` is null.

```
public setMyProperty (String myProperty) {
    this.myProperty = StringUtils.replaceChars(myProperty, ' ', '');
}
```